# "Cannot open: No such file or directory" when extracting a tar file

Tags: tar

I am trying to install Apache Cassandra that is a tar.gz file. The following is the output I am getting.

1st instance:

```
tar -zxvf apache-cassandra-2.0.3-bin.tar.gz
tar (child): apache-cassandra-2.0.3-bin.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

2nd instance:

```
tar -zxvf apache-cassandra-2.0.3-bin.tar.gz.gitignore
tar (child): apache-cassandra-2.0.3-bin.tar.gz.gitignore: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

What to do?
The files I need to install are in a disk and not copied to the machine. Does that matter?

Comment: Is file present in current directory? (use `pwd` to check present working directory, `cd` to change directory & `ls` to check filename)

Comment: @AJ how is this a duplicated?

Comment: @Braiam I thought the problem was in .tar.gz installation... sorry..

Answer (score 9):

Reason for your problem is in the error report.

```
Cannot open: No such file or directory
```

`cd`ed into the directory on which the `apache-cassandra-2.0.3-bin.tar.gz` file is located and then run the below command to extract it's content.

```
tar -zxvf filename.tar.gz   # Replace the filename with your's
```

Comment: I am having the same error when I use `-p` => `tar: p: Cannot open: No such file or directory
`